# Variable Passes down undefined to React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a simple app which searches for a specific element in the Periodic Table and displays details about that element.

In my main component I have a search filter: the user searches the element by name and then the app displays the Single Element component which displays more information about it.

```
   import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Elements = (elements, setElements, searchedElements) => {

  console.log(searchedElements)

if (searchedElements === undefined) {
  return null
}
if (searchedElements.length === 1) {
return (
  <div>
    <p>{searchedElements.atomicNumber}</p>
  </div>
)
}


}

const App = () =>  {
const [elements, setElements] = useState([])
const [newSearch, setNewSearch] = useState('')

const searchedElements = 
elements.filter(e => e.name.includes(newSearch))

console.log(searchedElements)

const handleChange = (event) => {
setNewSearch(event.target.value)
}

  useEffect(() => 
  {axios.get(`https://neelpatel05.pythonanywhere.com`)
  .then(response => {
    setElements(response.data)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
})}, [elements])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Element Reference App</h1>
<input onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search element by name"></input>
<Elements elements={elements} searchedElements={searchedElements} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The variable "searchedElements" filters the user's search terms against all the elements.

when using console.log(searchedElements) in the App component - the correct information is displayed.

However, the console.log(searchedElements) in the component "Element" is undefined - despite the fact I have passed it down from the App component.

Can anyone elaborate as to why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missusing function parameters. React components receive parameters as an object, that you can destructure like this:

```
const Elements = (props) => {
  const {elements, setElements, searchedElements} = props;
  ...
}
```

Plus, I think your `useEffect` has an infinite loop as you `setElement()` and watch for `[element]` dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is correct. You also answered what was going to be my next question with the infinite loop. I'm also going to post an answer of what I was trying to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Elements = ({searchedElements, elements, setElements}) => {

  console.log(searchedElements)

if (searchedElements === undefined) {
  return null
}
if (searchedElements.length === 1) {
return (
  <div>
    <p>{searchedElements[0].atomicNumber}</p>
  </div>
)
}


}
```

The answer is to either use props as in the answer above - or my answer which is simply putting curly braces where I'd forgotten to put them in the Element component